# $5y''+6y'=x^2+5x +3$ What is the $ y_p$ here? How to derive $y_p$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$5y''+6y'=x^2+5x +3$ What is the $ y_p$ here?

So I tried the usual. when the right hand side is polynomial degree of 2, my $ y_p = Ax^2 + Bx + C$. I then differentiate once and twice and sub them back in. But this time it doesn't work. I think it is because the left hand side is missing a constant term.

So for example in general,

$ay'' + by'= \sum _{i=0}^n\:\beta _i\:x^i$

Can someone help out? I don't want the answer. I just want to know how do you get the functional form of $y_p$? How do you derive it?

Can someone prove it (ie what y_p) is  or link a proof to me? Also, how do you mathematically express "some polynomial"?

Comment: You don't mean constant term. You mean $y$ term. Did you try $y_p$ to be a cubic polynomial?

Comment: Observe: the RHS is a quadratic and has a degree $2$ term. This term can only come from the $y'$ in LHS, so $y$ should be degree $\color{red}{3}$ polynomial.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Thanks for the answer. can you link me some sort of mathematical proof as to why I have to use degree 3 polynomial?

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi Ted, thanks for the comment. Yes after I put it into some online calculator. In which it used degree of 3. But I want a more rigorous  mathematical proof of why that is true.

Comment: Proof? The first derivative has to give you a quadratic.

Comment: @TedShifrin Well maybe not proof sorry, more like derification, from lets say $ay'' + by' = \sum _{i=0}^n\:\beta _i\:x^i$

Answer (score 2):

This is how we know that the particular solution is a polynomial of degree $3$. Since the right hand side is polynomial of degree $2$, differentiate thrice to obtain the following equation:

$$
\begin{align}
0&=5\frac{d^{5}y}{dx^{5}}+6\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}\\
\\
&=5\left(\frac{d^{5}y}{dx^{5}}+\frac{6}{5}\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}\right)\\
\\
&= 5\left(e^{\frac{6}{5}x}\frac{d^{5}y}{dx^{5}}+\frac{6}{5}e^{\frac{6}{5}x}\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}\right)\\
\\
&=5\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\frac{6}{5}x}\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

This is equivalent to:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}&=Ce^{-\frac{6}{5}x}\\
\\
y&=C_{1}e^{-\frac{6}{5}x}+C_{2}+C_{3}x+C_{4}x^{2}+C_{5}x^{3}
\end{align}
$$

If we substitute this back to the original equation, notice that any constant $C_{1},C_{2}$ will result in the equation evaluating to zero, that is why we call the first two terms homogenous solution. However, there are only a particular $C_{3},C_{4},C_{5}$ that will result in the right hand side, that is why we call the last three term particular solution.

Comment: Hi Rezha thanks for the answer. can you try to show in the more general form? $ay'' + by'  = \sum _{i=0}^n\:\beta _i\:x^i$ ?

Comment: Differentiate $n+1$ times, then proceed similarly as above. You will get that $y$ is a combination of exponential and polynomial of degree $n+1$

Comment: Hi Rezha, thanks but why n + 1 times? If I take the n + 1 derivative of a polynomial of degree n , wouldnt that make it zero?

Comment: @CountDOOKU bingo! now that the right hand side becomes zero, the left hand side is homogenous differential equation, no?

Comment: Hmmm Wouldn't that be 0 = 0? $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n\:+\:1}}\left(ay''\:+\:by'\right)\:=\:\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n\:+\:1}}\left(\sum \:\:_{i=0}^n\:\beta \:\:_i\:x^i\:\right)\:$ -- > $\left(ay^{\left(n+1+2\right)}\:+\:by^{\left(n+1+1\right)}\right)\:=\:0 $-- > $0 = 0$?

Comment: because I want A particular solution, I can take $y\:^{\left(n\right)}\:=\:0\: $then $y\:^{\left(n+1\right)}\:=\:0\:$ and any subsequent derivative is 0 no?

Comment: @CountDOOKU now read my answer but read slowly, how many times i differentiate the original equation, what kind of equation i get, what is the solution of this new equation, compare it to the homogenous and particular solution to the original equation

Comment: Hi Rezha, sorry can you please explain how you get $e^\frac{-6}{5} x$ in line 3

Answer (score 1):

I hope this post develops an intuition for you for how things are working here. The procedure is not quite rigorous, but I think having a heuristic proof is always better before moving to a rigourous one.

In your case, if the degree of $y$ is $n$, then the RHS is a degree-$2$ polynomial, and the LHS is degree $n-1$ polynomial. Clearly, $n=3$ is the only way this can happen.

Consider a general differential equation
$$ay^{(m)}+by^{(m-1)}+\cdots=P(x)$$
where $y^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$th derivative of $y$, and $P(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $p$.

Note that $y$ has to be a polynomial. (Think why!) Now, if the degree of $y$ is $n$, the LHS is a degree $n-m$ polynomial and the RHS is a degree $p$ polynomial. You can write it mathematically using the [Big-O Notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) as
$$\mathcal O(x^{n-m})=\mathcal O(x^p)$$
And for these two polynomials to be equal, we must have $n-m=p$ *i.e.* the function $y$ is a degree $(m+p)$ polynomial. Then you can simply proceed by doing the usual - taking the general form of a polynomial and proceeding. There might be simpler ways depending upon the question though.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: In general, the left side will still be a degree-$n$ polynomial due to the last term. If the last term on the left is $y^{(k)}$, the left side has degree $n-k$. In the given task, $k=1$, so $n=3$ is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

$y$   particular I will call it $Y_{p}$.

First we should find the homogenous solution $Y_{h}$

$5y''+6y'=0$

the characteristic equation is:

$5t^{2}+6t=0$

then:

$t=0 $ and $t=\frac{-6}{5}$

so $Y_{h}=c_{1}e^{0x}+c_{2}e^{\frac{-6}{5}x}=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{\frac{-6}{5}x}$

In $Y_{h}$ we have $c_{1}$ a constant term which is similar to the constant term $C$ in $Ax^{2}+Bx+C$ so $Ax^{2}+Bx+C$ is not good as form for $Y_{p}$

So we will choose $Y_{p}=x(Ax^{2}+Bx+C)=Ax^{3}+Bx^{2}+Cx$

So $Y_{p}'=3Ax^{2}+2Bx+C$

$Y_{p}''=6Ax+2B$

$5Y_{p}''+6Y_{p}'=x^{2}+5x+3$

then:  $5Y_{p}''+6Y_{p}'=(30Ax+10B)+(18Ax^{2}+12Bx+6C)=(18A)x^{2}+(30A+12B)x+(10B+6C)=x^{2}+5x+3$

By equating coefficients:

$A=\frac{1}{18} ,B=\frac{5}{18} ,$ and $C=\frac{2}{54}$

So $Y_{p}=\frac{1}{18}x^{3}+\frac{5}{18}x^{2}+\frac{2}{54}x$.

Good book to read about this method called (undetermined coefficients) and its proof is :

william e boyce richard c diprima elementary differential equations wiley 2012:

Chapter: 3 ,Section:5 , page: 175.

Now for clarifying your example I will use annihilator approach (Also you should first find $Y_{h}$ but we found it above so we are ready for this method).

$y'$ can be represented by notation $Dy$

$y''$ can be represented by notation $D^{2}y$

.

.

.

$y^{(n)}$ can be represented by notation $D^{n}y$

So your example :

$5y''+6y'=x^{2}+5x+3$

becomes:

$5D^{2}y+6Dy=x^{2}+5x+3$

$D^{3}(5D^{2}y+6Dy)=D^{3}(x^{2}+5x+3)$

$5D^{5}y+6D^{4}y=0$

characteristic equation is:

$5t^{5}+6t^{4}=0$

$5t^{5}+6t^{4}=t^{4}(5t+6)=0$

so

$t=0,0,0,0,\frac{-6}{5}$

so \begin{align*} 
\\&y=c_{0}+c_{1}x+x_{2}x^2+c_{3}x^{3}+c_{4}e^{\frac{-6}{5}}\\&=c_{1}x+x_{2}x^2+c_{3}x^{3}+(c_{0}+c_{4}e^{\frac{-6}{5}})\\&=c_{1}x+x_{2}x^2+c_{3}x^{3}+Y_{h}\end{align*}

So $Y_{p}=c_{1}x+x_{2}x^2+c_{3}x^{3}$ and the solution as above.

Now in general $a_{n}y^{(n)}+...+a_{1}y'+a_{0}y=(a_{n}D^{n}+...+a_{1}D+a_{0})y=f(x)$

First case: If $f(x)=1,x,x^{2},...x^{n-1}$   are annihilated (are made zero) by $D^{n}$

we take example about it above.

and the general differential equation is solved as following:

$D^{n}(a_{n}D^{n}+...+a_{1}D+a_{0})y=D^{n}f(x)=0$ and then by characteristic equation.

Second case: If $f(x)=e^{\alpha{x}},xe^{\alpha{x}},...,x^{n-1}e^{\alpha{x}}$ are annihilated (are made zero) by $(D-\alpha)^{n}$

for example of annihilating  $f(x)=e^{3x}+xe^{3x}$ is annihilated by $(D-3)^2$

\begin{align*}(D-3)^2(e^{3x}+xe^{3x})&=(D^{2}-6D+9)(e^{3x}+xe^{3x})\\&=(D^{2}e^{3x}-6De^{3x}+9e^{3x})+(D^{2}xe^{3x}-6Dxe^{3x}+9xe^{3x})\\&=(9e^{3x}-18e^{3x}+9e^{3x})+((9x+6)e^{3x}+(-18x-6)e^{3x}+9xe^{3x})\\&=0
\end{align*}

then for general solution of general  differential equation:

$(D-\alpha)^{n}(a_{n}D^{n}+...+a_{1}D+a_{0})y=(D-\alpha)^{n}f(x)=0$ and then by characteristic equation.

Third case: If $f(x)=e^{\alpha{x}}\cos{\beta{x}},xe^{\alpha{x}}\cos{\beta{x}},...,x^{n-1}e^{\alpha{x}}\cos{\beta{x}}$ then they are annihilated (are made zero) by $(D^{2}-2\alpha D+(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{2})^{n}$

note that : $(D^{2}+\beta^{2})(sin{\beta{x}})=0$ and $(D^{2}+\beta^{2})(cos{\beta{x}})=0$

then for general solution of general  differential equation:

$(D^{2}-2\alpha D+(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{2})^{n}(a_{n}D^{n}+...+a_{1}D+a_{0})y=(D^{2}-2\alpha D+(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{2})^{n}f(x)=0$ and then by characteristic equation.

All the above cases for annihilators of different types of $f(x)$ are proven by induction  and then you solve by characteristic equation after it becomes homogenous equation.

The process is similar to my solution of your example.

This method of annihilator is from  book:

A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications

Comment: @CountDOOKU I will try to edit the answer to add more details.

Comment: @CountDOOKU I have edited it with generalization even more  than you asked.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud thanks for answer. Can you explain why $a_{n}y^{n}+...+a_{1}y'+a_{0}y=(a_{n}D^{n}+...+a_{1}D+a_{0})y=f(x)$?. Why is the $y$ term factored out?

Comment: first:The nth derivative of y is written $y^{(n)}$ , sorry it was also mistake in my answer but I corrected it.

second: we factored y because it helped us with writing the characteristic equation when we multiply by the annihilator of f(x) .

Third: Also I gave you two references to read more about my solution.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, 1 more question, can $Y_{p}= c_{0} + c_{1}x+x_{2}x^2+c_{3}x^{3}$? IE can i add the constant ?

Comment: Mahmoud what if I add a constant to the particular solution. What is the effect? Is it redundant?

Comment: yes it is  redundant because in your ode you have $y',y''$ so it will be zero.

Comment: In general ... If we determine $Y_{p}$ to be $Y_{p}=c_{0}+c_{1}x$ and we add the  redundant term $c_{2}x^{2}$ then it becomes $Y_{p}=c_{0}+c_{1}x+c_{2}x^{2}$
then when we solve it...it will turn out that $c_{2}=0$, So In general coefficient of redundant terms will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that the equation in its original form is integrable once to give
$$
5y'+6y=\frac13x^3+\frac52x+3x,
$$
leaving the integration constant at zero. Now the method of undetermined coefficients tells us that a particular solution can be found that is a cubic polynomial.